# PageLayout not rendering for Anonymous Users

Tags: 2013, office-365, page-layout, anonymous-authentication

I have an external SharePoint Online site. The issue I am having is that the Page Layout I'm using does not render at all for anonymous users. My Masterpage renders fine and the Page Layout works great when logged into Office 365. (Also, I have published the Page Layout so I know that's not the issue.)

Does anyone know how to remember this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue. I was publishing via Designer. You must publish thru SharePoint.